Trigger a file download in a web page, from a local file
I am working in a webpage built with just html, css and javascript, and i want to download a word document when the user click a link.
I saw some options but all required to have the document hosted online (https://...)
I have the document saved locally on my PC. I wonder if there is a way to host this document within my folder with html/js/css and that by clicking it it can be downloaded without having to host it in another online service.

It can be done so you can download it on your computer, but it won't be publicly accessible so no one else can download it. Is that your intention? That doesn't seem to make much sense.

To make a file downloadable for anyone you need a web server. You can run a web server locally and then use your local IP address to link to it. You can even use a domain name.

Yes I want it to be  publicly accessible, So I understand that it is necessary to upload it to an online server.

Uploading the file to a normal web host is the easiest solution, yes.

I have seen people providing links (= url) from cloud storage solutions. So that's another option.

Why do you want to "download" a file, that is alreay stored on your machine? But if you want anyone to be able to download that document, you have to put it in a location where anyone can access it. Your machine is (typically) not such a location.

But if you are already hosting your website somewhere (how would people otherwise be able to access it), you can of course also just upload your word document to the same location

The design lacks a clear goal. If you will have everything (your website and even the word document) on the same file system, then you should configure your web server (which hosts your website) in such a way that this word document becomes publicly accessible via the same web server. The underlying question which you should answer is: "what web server are you using?". And the question we will answer is: "how to make a file become publicly accessible on so and so web server from so and so file system".
